# How to echo html and include php

Tags: php

I want to make some edits live but I need to edit in same time when user are on website. So I have this but php is commented in website source:

```
 <?php

if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "86.115.14.77"){ 
                echo "<li class='dropdown hv'>
                    <a style='cursor:pointer' class='dropdown-toggle ' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                        <i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i> Contul meu
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                            <li>
                                <?php include('form_logare.php'); ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </li>";
 } else{ 
            echo   "<li class='dropdown hv'>
                    <a style='cursor:pointer' class='dropdown-toggle ' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                        <i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i> Contul meu
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                            <li>
                                <?php include('form_logare.php'); ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </li>";
}
?>
```

So `<?php include('form_logare.php');?>` is become commented on front side.

<< is become comment in source of website.

Comment: "but php is commented in website source" - what does that mean? To me, both outputs look the same

Comment: Okay, you want to change it, but what is it that's broken? There is no description of an issue here - please expand on this or, as much as we want to, we cannot help

Comment: look the same but on front-side is not included form_logare.php is because of this maybe? i have <?php  echo " html <?php include('form_logare.php');?> ?>  <<< is php inside of php and this include is html format not php anymore to include that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include your php file contents to your echo, you should concatenate it like this:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "86.115.14.77"){ 
                echo "<li class='dropdown hv'>
                    <a style='cursor:pointer' class='dropdown-toggle ' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                        <i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i> Contul meu
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                            <li>" . include('form_logare.php') . "</li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </li>";
 } else{ 
            echo   "<li class='dropdown hv'>
                    <a style='cursor:pointer' class='dropdown-toggle ' data-toggle='dropdown'>
                        <i class='fa fa-user' aria-hidden='true'></i> Contul meu
                        <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                            <li>". include('form_logare.php') . "</li>
                        </ul>
                    </a>
                </li>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The include function will be rendered literally because it is inside the quotes. You need to concatenate it like this.

```
  "<li>" . include('form_logare.php') . "</li>";
```